# How do I extend or derive from the RibbonToggleButton created by the Microsoft RibbonFactory?

Tags: c#, winforms, vsto, extends, derived-class

How do I extend/derive from `RibbonToggleButton` in this scenario?

I have a Microsoft Word VSTO add-in. My goal is to create a "custom" class `MyRibbonToggleButton` that extends or derives from `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonToggleButton`. I want to extend/derive because there is at least one custom property by which I want to extend the `RibbonToggleButton` class.

My approach is to observe how a `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonToggleButton` is created and then derive `MyRibbonToggleButton` class from what I see.

**1. I created a new Word VSTO Project**

[image]

[image]

**2. Added a ribbon**

[image]

**3. Designed the ribbon, adding a RibbonToggleButton**

[image]

When I examine the designer, I can see that a `RibbonToggleButton` object is instantiated by calling the ribbon's `Factory.CreateRibbonToggleButton()`.

[image]

Since the type of the object returned is `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonToggleButton`, I created a custom class and attempted to derive from `RibbonToggleButton`.

[image]

This is when I became aware that `RibbonToggleButton` is an interface. As such, my custom class has some 30 or so undefined properties, methods, events, etc.. I don't want to write the code behind all these. Rather, I want to utilize the properties, methods, and events provided in the base `RibbonToggleButton` class by Microsoft and I want to add at least one custom property.

Now I'm in trouble because I'm having a hard time understanding interfaces in general, not to mention how to extend/derive from one.  I'm confused because I know there must be a concrete `RibbonToggleButton` object returned by `Factory.CreateRibbonToggleButton()` at run time. Again: I want to utilize the properties, methods, and events provided in the base `RibbonToggleButton` class by Microsoft and I want to add at least one custom property.

How do I extend/derive from `RibbonToggleButton` in this scenario?

Comment: You cannot derive from or customize the control beyond what the control itself allows. Try to be more specific - what is it exactly you are attempting to customize and why?

Comment: Please do 1-2-3 and look at at `Ribbon1.Designer1.cs` as you read the following: I want to customize the class of the object returned by `this.Factory.CreateRibbonToggleButton()` because I need a two-way `has-a` relationship between individual `RibbonToggleButton` objects and my individual `System,Windows.Controls.UserControl` class objects (e.g., `MyUserControl : UserControl`). In other words, `MyUserControl` currently defines a `RibbonToggleButton AssociatedToggleButton` property, and I want each `RibbonToggleButton` object to have a `UserControl AssociatedUserControl` property.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that and I am not sure why you even need it. I'd also avoid ribbon designer if you can help it - just return the ribbon XML from your code.

Each ribbon control has an id (defined in you ribbon XML). If you need to keep your custom control in sync with a ribbon control, refresh the ribbon (by calling IRibbonUI.Invalidate or IRibbonUI.InvalidateControl. That will cause the ribbon to fire custom callbacks on your control (you need to specify them in ribbon XML), such as getImage, getText, etc. You can then return the updated information as appropriate.